# How to apply CIFilter to CALayer

Tags: ios, core-image

I'm trying to understand how to apply CIFilter on a CALayer using the filter array property. According to the documentation this should be available from iOS5.

This is my code so far.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    CIFilter *gradientFilter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CILinearGradient"];
    [gradientFilter setValue:[CIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0] forKey:@"inputColor0"];
    [gradientFilter setValue:[CIVector vectorWithX:0 Y:0] forKey:@"inputPoint0"];
    [gradientFilter setValue:[CIColor colorWithRed:1 green:1 blue:1] forKey:@"inputColor1"];
    [gradientFilter setValue:[CIVector vectorWithX:0 Y:200] forKey:@"inputPoint1"];

    self.view.layer.filters = @[gradientFilter];
    [self.view setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

The self.view is just an empty UIView with backgroundColor set to green.

I know that I can create a gradient in other ways but if this works I'm going to apply more filters so this is just for testing the system.

All the examples I've found is applying filters on UIImage and I can't get those to work for me...

Comment: Mr.Johan, kindly try this self.view.layer.filters = [NSArray arrayWithObject:gradientFilter];

Comment: Thanks for your comment Bala but [NSArray arrayWithObject:gradientFilter] is the same as @[gradientFilter]. New Objective-C syntax

Comment: Sorry I don't know that!. :) and thanks for that new Objective-C Syntax.

Comment: Have you ever found an answer to this? I'm facing the exact same situation.

Comment: The answer I got was that filters will only work on images, not views.
I needed filters to solve two things. Bluring the background and adding a gradient. I solved the bluring by saving the view to a UIImage and apply the filter and add the filtered image as a transparent view over the original view. The gradient was solved with a CAGradientLayer.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to render the layer into an image and then set the image as `inputImage` to the filter, then draw the `outputImage` in the layer.